# How to remove space between widgets in Column in flutter?

Tags: layout, dart, flutter

I looked for the answer but I couldn't found.

Why Column widget gives space between child widgets?
I wanna remove this for my widget layout. Below is my code and space position.

[image]

Code!!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Clock',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.blue
      ),
      home: Social(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class Social extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                ClipOval(
                  clipper: CircleClipper(),
                  child: Image.asset('assets/irene.jpg')
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            'Irene',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 15.0
                            )
                          )
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text('Yesterday, Ney York')
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: IconButton(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                    onPressed: (){},
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.1,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
            child: Card(
              child: Image.asset('assets/irene.jpg'),
              color: Colors.white,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
              elevation: 10.0,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0,right: 30.0,top: 15.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/like.png'), 
                  width: 30.0,
                  height: 30.0,
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 20.0,),
                Image.asset('assets/chat.png'),
                Expanded(child: Container()),
                Image.asset('assets/share.png'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(child: Container()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CircleClipper extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  @override
  Rect getClip(Size size) {
    return Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(size.width/2,size.height/4), radius: size.width/3);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Rect> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

How can I fix it and what widgets I have to use?
To make a size of child widget of Column, I have to use Flexible,Expanded etc.
Is there an any other widgets which can satisfy this condition?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because you are using `Flexible` and it expands the `Widget` inside to fill the available space.

Change this :

```
   body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
```

To this:

```
   body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 60.0,
```

And it should work

Comment: Before the answer, I modified `Row` to `Stack` and used `Positioned`, anyway thx

Answer (score 3):

I see the problem isn't in the Column widget, it's in the first child of it, it takes longer height than you expect, I recommend to use [Widget inspector](https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/inspector) for diagnosing layout issues in the future.

Here is the fix:

**1-** No need here for the widget, just remove it.

```
Flexible(
        flex: 1, ...)
```

**2-** Set proper dimensions to your avatar image by wrapping it in a `Container` like this:

```
Container(
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  child: ClipOval(clipper: CircleClipper(), child: Image.asset('assets/irene.jpg')),
)
```

Finally, here is the updated full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

    void main() {
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Clock',
          theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.blue),
          home: Social(),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        );
      }
    }

    class Social extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.white, elevation: 0.0),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    child: ClipOval(clipper: CircleClipper(), child: Image.asset('assets/irene.jpg')),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text('Irene',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15.0))),
                          Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: Text('Yesterday, Ney York'))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: IconButton(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                child: Card(
                  child: Image.asset('assets/irene.jpg'),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                  elevation: 10.0,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0, top: 15.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.thumb_up, color: Colors.black),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Icon(Icons.chat, color: Colors.black),
                    Expanded(child: Container()),
                    Icon(Icons.share, color: Colors.black),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(child: Container()),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```